# Error: Can't open display: 0

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming

I installed WSL2 and I want to access WSL2 GUI apps from Windows 10. For this, I installed Xming and start it in "No client" mode. Xming startes, ok. After I open the WSL2 terminal and there execute these commands

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

And after

```
xeyes
```

And get error

```
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

X11Forwarding checked, yes.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Solved problem with executing this command

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0
```

This command can also be added in shell initialization files, for example, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` etc.

Also make sure to allow public access of X server running in Windows 10.
For **VcXsrv**, `-ac` option is most important because it allows public access.
For **Xming**, run through XLaunch and in the part "Specify parameter settings" select "No Access Control".

For more see this discussion [Microsoft/WSL: Can't use X-Server in WSL2](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4106).

Comment: For anybody out there that isn't sure what adding the `-ac` option means, and can't get to the link in the answer, when you run your X server, there should be a step near the end where you can add `Additional parameters for VcXsrv`, you type the `-ac` in there.  That solved my problem after the export provided above.

Comment: Thanks for the one-liner!  Have to modify this if your "nameserver" is not the same as your host.  About WSL2 -  Your WSL2 instance uses a separate network stack, so you need a way to discover what you're host IP is from within your WSL2 instance.

Comment: `export DISPLAY=$(ip route get 0.0.0.0 | awk '{print $NF}'):0` can be used to export your display to the interface IP responsible for your route to the internet (WSL1 only).

Comment: I confirm `export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0` worked for WSL2 with Windows10x64 May 2004.

Comment: Holy crap, this worked after sifting through *endless* stack overflow posts to figure out why the stupid gui wasn't working

Answer (score 13):

I encountered this issue after changing the version of my WSL Ubuntu distribution from 1 to 2. Using

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0
```

was not sufficient. According to https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6181 I needed to reconfigure the firewall. This can be done by

- going to Advanced Security -> Inbound rules (admin permissions required)
- delete all rules for Vcxsvr
- restarting Vcxsvr, which prompts you to set Windows Firewall for this program
- allow all (or enough) access

After these 2 changes, the problem was solved.

Comment: I was able to enable the existing rules for the same effect.

Comment: This is important!

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Open PowerShell as Administrator and run: `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow`
2. Now open WSL2 and run: `export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0`
3. Now `xeyes`

Answer (score 0):

For coLinux using `eth0=slirp` with the default configuration, Xming on the Windows host can be accessed using `export DISPLAY=10.0.2.2:0` (or 0.0). Using [biswapriyo](https://superuser.com/users/726810/biswapriyo)'s solution would not work in this case because slirp sets the resolver IP to 10.0.2.3, but his answer made me realize what I was doing wrong.